# Generating in memory zip file at server and sending to client as download Node.JS

Tags: node.js, download, zip, server, in-memory

I'm trying to generate a zip file in memory on the server and sending it to the client as a download file.

Basically, there's a html page where the client types what file he wants.
The server receives what the client typed (via socket.io) and does a search on a mongodb. At this point, the server returns a link like this one

```
    <a href='#' onclick='socket.emit("generateFile", id, path); return false;'>link</a>
```

Where id is the id of the entry in the database and path is the location of one of the files that will be in the zip.
After that, that server is supposed the create a json containing the entry that has that id and zip it along with some local files available on the server. My question is: how do I send this generated zip to the client? Remember: I want to send it without having  to  save it in the server's hdd. I tried using Express after the zip is created but the code doesn't reach this piece:

```
    app.get('/', function(res, req)
    {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
        res.send(generatedZipFile)
    })
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is from express-static-zip implementation

```
var contentType = mime.lookup(name);
            if (contentType != 'application/octet-stream') {
                res.set('Content-type', contentType);
                var charSet = mime.charsets.lookup(contentType);
                if (charSet) {
                    entryData = entryData.toString(charSet);
                }
            }

            res.status(200).send(entryData);
```

You might want to set status code and mime format.

Comment: But this one needs a static zip file. I am generating the zip file in runtime and I want to send it to the client without having to save it in the server's disk.